# Run-time check failure in recursive function

Tags: recursion, fortran, runtime, intel-fortran

When I compile my program with runtime-checks, I get the following error (and I have no idea why):

```
ifort -check all test.f90 -o test
./test
forrtl: severe (193): Run-Time Check Failure. The variable 'my_sum$2$_2' is being used without being defined
Image        PC                     Routine           Line           Source
sum          0000000000403098       Unknown              Unknown     Unknown 
sum          0000000000403098       Unknown              Unknown     Unknown 
sum          0000000000403098       Unknown              Unknown     Unknown 
sum          0000000000403098       Unknown              Unknown     Unknown 
.
.
.
sum          0000000000403098       Unknown              Unknown     Unknown 
sum          0000000000402EAF       Unknown              Unknown     Unknown 
sum          0000000000402DE6       Unknown              Unknown     Unknown 
libc.so.6    00007F7FEB268BE5       Unknown              Unknown     Unknown 
sum          0000000000402CD9       Unknown              Unknown     Unknown
```

The code is:

```
program test

   implicit none
   real(8) :: x

   x=my_sum(lambda_i,0,200)
   print*,x

contains

   function lambda_i(n) result(i)
      real(8) :: i
      integer,intent(in) :: n
      i=dble(n)
   end function

   recursive function my_sum(f,i,n) result(s)
      implicit none
      real(8) :: s
      integer, intent(in) :: i,n
      interface
         function f(n)
         implicit none
         real(8) :: f
         integer,intent(in) :: n
         end function
      end interface

      if ( n .ge. 0 ) s=f(n)+my_sum(f,i,n-1)
   end function

end program
```

Anyone an idea? Without the check the program runs fine unless I reach the recursion limit.

Comment: My ifort yields the value 20100, without crashing (version 14 on Windows). Gfortran gives the same value, and Abosft 2014 can't compile (because it wants lambda_i declared external, even though it's an internal function). If I "externalize" lambda_i, I still get 20100.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is

```
if ( n .ge. 0 ) s=f(n)+my_sum(f,i,n-1)
```

Once you reach `n .lt. 0`, the return value `s` is not defined, and the function returns an undefined variable (just as `ifort` complains). Since this is the final step in your recursion, and all other results depend on that, the total result is undefined.

This can be avoided by using

```
if ( n .ge. 0 ) then 
  s=f(n)+my_sum(f,i,n-1)
else
  s=0._8
endif
```

Comment: You are right, of course, but it's funny that you get the same value with three compilers. And it's also the value you get if you set s=0 in the else clause you suggest. That is, all of them seem to initialize to zero.